# In my example, do I need parentheses?

Tags: parentheses

(ϕ_1 ) ̂ is the first stage (the estimated effect of the MLDA on alcohol consumption). (ρ_1 ) ̂ is the reduced form (the estimated effect of the MLDA on either overall deaths, motor vehicle fatalities, or drinking fatalities).

Or, can I just put a comma instead like in the following:

(ϕ_1 ) ̂ is the first stage, the estimated effect of the MLDA on alcohol consumption. (ρ_1 ) ̂ is the reduced form, the estimated effect of the MLDA on either overall deaths, motor vehicle fatalities, or drinking fatalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a colon. What follows the colon is a description of what precedes it. The colon effectively introduces a list with a single element.

> **ϕ<sub>1</sub>′** is the first stage: the estimated effect of the MLDA on alcohol consumption.
>   **ρ<sub>1</sub>′** is the reduced form: the estimated effect of the MLDA on either overall deaths, motor vehicle fatalities, or drinking fatalities.